# TableviewCell takes more time to on didselect method for first time only

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am having a table view when i select any cell at particular index then it call didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

But for the first time when the app is opened everytime it takes 5 to 6 second of time to initialize next VC

M not doing any kind of large processing on viewwillappear of next vc

my code for didselect method:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in


            let obj: NewService = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddService") as! NewService
            print("delay 0")
            let casell: Case = self.caseList[indexPath.row]
            print("delay 1")
            obj.caseNo = String(casell.CasesID)
            print("delay 2")
            obj.indexNo = (indexPath.row)
            print("delay 3")
            navigationController!.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
            print("delay 4")
        }
```

My next vc for add service have this :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSLog(@"delay 5");

        myServiceList = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"serviceList"];
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];

        self.txtvwDesc.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
        self.txtvwDesc.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;

        self.txtDate.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
        self.txtDate.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;

        self.txtMinute.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
        self.txtMinute.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;


        self.title = [@"Case No : " stringByAppendingString: self.caseNo];
        // self.title = @"Moin";
        self.btnservice.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;

        [self.txtDate setDropDownMode:IQDropDownModeDatePicker];
        NSLog(@"delay 6");
    });

}
```

Comment: Why are you dispatching that code in `viewWillAppear`?  That will make your app less responsive, not more.  You should use the time profiler instrument to identify where the delay is occuring

Comment: What about viewDidLoad method of your next viewController? Is there anything which takes more time to load?

Comment: No viewwillappear is blank

Comment: and i have kept all in viewwillappear beacuse i want to load the case number everytime after back and delay is actually after delay 4